# @yield(Str::limit('text', 10)) does not work - Laravel

Tags: laravel

My current code

```
<meta name="description" content="Download @yield('description_custom')">
```

I want set limit for my 'description_custom'

I tried

```
<meta name="description" content="Download @yield(Str::limit('description_custom', 10))">
```

But i receive 500 error

Comment: What are you attempting to do exactly? The code you are attempting will always try and yield "descriptio..."

Answer (score 0):

You can edit a variable with came from `'description_custom'` with `View::getSections()`
In you blade file:

```
{{ View::getSections()['description_custom'] = str_limit(View::getSections()['description_custom'],10,'...')  }}
```

or if you are in laravel 7 you also can try

```
{{ View::getSections()['description_custom'] = Str::limit('description_custom', 10) }}
```

and you meta remains it was

```
<meta name="description" content="Download @yield('description_custom')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved

```
<meta name="description" content="{{\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($description,160) }}">
```